# How to call build.gradle from another build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project (Main project with sub projects) structure

```
ProjectMain
    build.gradle

Project1
    release
        my.jar
    build.gradle
```

The ProjectMain need jar `Project1/release/my.jar`. In `build.gradle` for `Project1` I release logic for creatting jar. It is necessary that when `ProjectMain` assebly used dependency of `my.jar`.

How I can do it? (desirable with groovy code).

P.S. before I used ant, and write simple xml and it works

```
<target name="one"?
    <path id="project.classpath">
              <fileset dir="${Project1.release}">
                  <patternset includes="**/*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
    </path>
</target>

<target name="Two">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${out}" debug="on">
              <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"calling" a different build.gradle isn't the right way to go about this. You should look into [gradle multi-project setup](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies) If you setup as a multi-project, gradle manages building upstream dependency projects first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run external build.gradle, you can import another build.gradle into your build.gradle by using "apply from".

Put this into "ProjectMain/Build.gradle".
(I think it is local file)

```
apply from:"file://[PJ_DIR]/Project1/build.gradle";
```

And this is like Project1's build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
version = 1.0
task makejar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    baseName = "my"
}
```